# post multipart/form-data variable and image using curl

Tags: php, image, curl, multipartform-data

My company has an html form to send variables and update image (jpeg) to the server, I tried to automate it using curl, but got stuck. I can send variables but not the image.

I used "tamper data" firefox and noticed that my form send the following variables to the server:

```
-----------------------------291231848620019\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="pin"\r\n\r\ndf8794b1ec63c7094f6498f7a1322bcc\r\n-----------------------------291231848620019\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="yourdata"\r\n\r\nonly test\r\n-----------------------------291231848620019\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="your_file"; filename="chansy.jpg"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n{content-of-image-file-here}\r\n-----------------------------291231848620019\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="birth_date[]"\r\n\r\n1\r\n-----------------------------291231848620019\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="birth_date[]"\r\n\r\n1\r\n-----------------------------291231848620019\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="birth_date[]"\r\n\r\n1970\r\n-----------------------------291231848620019\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="your_email"\r\n\r\nkrunker@asia.com\r\n-----------------------------291231848620019\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="code"\r\n\r\n\r\n-----------------------------291231848620019\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="pass"\r\n\r\npass_sample\r\n-----------------------------291231848620019\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="act"\r\n\r\nUpdate Changes\r\n-----------------------------291231848620019\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="your_name"\r\n\r\njust me\r\n-----------------------------291231848620019--\r\n
```

here is the code i used on array postfields:

```
$img=file_get_contents($filename);    
$data = array('pin' => $pin, 'yourdata' => $_POST['yourdata'], 'your_file'=>$img, 'filename' =>$filename, 'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg', 'birth_date[]' => $_POST['birth_date'], 'birth_date[]' => $_POST['birth_month'], 'birth_date[]' => $_POST['birth_year'], 'your_email' => $_POST['your_email'], 'pass' => $_POST['pass'], 'act' => 'Update changes', 'your_name' => $_POST['your_name']);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch , CURL_HTTPHEADER , "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://internalweb.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://internalweb.com/profile");
$page = curl_exec($ch);
```

On the result, when I run my script, it can update those variables, but no luck with the image.. i am so confuse... what should i do to put in variable?

I am learning everything from google, and now i am stuck since i dont have any knowledge in deep programming, can you please help me what to do to put image in $data array?

I tried to look on the thread of:
[multipart/form-data into array not processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983722/multipart-form-data-into-array-not-processing)
[multipart/form-data php curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676345/multipart-form-data-php-curl)
[Posting raw image data as multipart/form-data in curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905942/posting-raw-image-data-as-multipart-form-data-in-curl?rq=1)

**note:**
I tried to follow Hassan's suggestion, but not work still. Does anyone know how to convert this:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="your_file"; filename="merc.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
$contentfile
```

into $data array for curl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you upload a file to server using curl, you need to specify the `@` sign before the file path. For example this image file:

```
$img = '/var/tmp/someimg.jpg';  // must be full path
```

Then in your post data, it should be:

```
'your_file' => '@' . $img,
```

Also, remove the following header from your curl code. Curl will automatically set this header with length based on your parameters.

```
curl_setopt($ch , CURL_HTTPHEADER , "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" );
```

Finally make sure your other parameter values are correct. And, also enable the verbose mode, so that you can see the output from curl `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, the "usual data" is not updated, and the image still not uploaded.

I need to know how to convert this: 

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="your_file"; filename="merc.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
$contentfile

into $data array....

Comment: @n3m0 these will add automatically. Run your code enabling the verbose mode as i mentioned earlier, and check yourself whats going on!

Comment: i did, the image still not uploaded... 
If i am using windows, i use "C:\path\filename.ext", right?

Comment: @n3m0 `\\` requires instead of `\ ` Also you can use `c:/path/filename.ext`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue, I needed to upload files to this API :

http://www.sonicapi.com/docs/api/file-upload

Generally it is straight forward to upload but sometimes there are servers who need more information about what you're sending.

In my case it needed to have the `ContentDisposition` header `Name` property set to `"file"` and the `FileName` property set to the file name of the file being uploaded.

As soon as I've added the following code everything worked perfectly :

```
string name = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = 
    new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
{
    Name = "\"file\"",
    FileName = String.Format("\"{0}\"", name)
};
streamContent.Headers.ContentType = 
    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
```

**Now your problem is certainly not the same**

Either you can get the docs about the service, or try the following :

Here's my approach on how I fixed the issue in my case.

- I ran [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) in background while posting the form manually (from web browser).
- I looked a the *Raw* tab in *Inspectors* to see what it was doing.
- By comparing the same for my code and the web browser, I quickly figured out what was wrong

Just a guess it seems to be on an Intranet, we can't really take a look to tell what's wrong.

Comment: Well, its closed source, so I dont think I will have docs from my company :).
But I do will try Fiddler... thank you so much! :)

Comment: If you can't get it right then update your post with both logs so people can help.

Comment: The result is same like i used with "Tamper Data" add on for firefox bro, I need to change this

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="citizen_file"; filename="merc.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

into array of $data :(

Comment: sorry, i mean 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="your_file"; filename="filename.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

Answer (score 0):

Ok ereveryone, I will close this issue and thank you so much for the help! Do really appreciate it :)

I tried to simulate it on my own server, it seem that **i can successfully upload the file using curl**  *credit to hassan :) *

But dunno how my production's web / my company's website didnt receive the image file I sent via curl. Since the sourcecode of the destination is closed source, so i can not do much from my side except keep trying if I have something new come up lol.

so once again, thank you, you guys made me more understand what is curl.

Regards,

n3m0